# TLS handshake cipher list

Tags: apache, ssl, jboss, encryption

I have a question on the TLS initial handshake.
(I am no expert, so I'd love an easy to grasp explanation).

According to wikipedia:

*Negotiation Phase:

1. A client sends a ClientHello message specifying the highest TLS protocol version it supports, a random number, a list of suggested cipher suites and compression methods.
2. The server responds with a ServerHello message, containing the chosen protocol version, a random number, cipher suite and compression method from the choices offered by the client. The server may also send a session id as part of the message to perform a resumed handshake.*

What I am trying to do is to change the cipher list sent during the ClientHello phase (make it only include 128bit + ciphers).

When a client sends a ClientHello message to my server (jboss) I can limit the ciphers that jboss can handle by playing around with the server.xml file and adding something like

```
ciphers="DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA,DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA,DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA,DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA256-SHA,AES256-SHA,CAMELLIA256-SHA,PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA,EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA,EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA,DES-CBC3-SHA,PSK-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA,DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA,DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA,DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA,DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA128-SHA,AES128-SHA,CAMELLIA128-SHA,PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA"
```

I am wondering though if that is sufficient when my server is contacting another server (thus acting like a client) and starts the handshake itself.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it isn't. server.xml defines the behaviour of the server connector, not SSL clients. You would have to set the enabled cipher suites on your own SSLSocket or HttpsURLConnection or whatever you are using to connect as a client.

Comment: thanks for the reply. So is there a way to configure this with a server wide configuration file of some kind?

Comment: @user2835461 I've just answered that. If you want a global configuration file you will have to implement it yourself.